# How do I use WHERE in macro with two different tables?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have two tables and I want to delete the entire row from table1 where value of its `field_m` is the same as `table2`'s `field_m` using a macro.

In the macro I used the RunSQL function and tried using the following:

```
DELETE * FROM table1 WHERE table1.field_m = table2.field_m
```

I have used it with and without bracketing and cannot get it to work. I either get a prompt for the value of `table1.field_m` and `table2.field_m` or I get invalid bracketing.

I tried googling this but cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the `DELETE ... FROM ... JOIN` syntax:

```
DELETE table1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field_m = table2.field_m
```

Or a subquery:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE field_m IN (SELECT field_m FROM table2)
```

Comment: Using the first suggestion I get prompted with "Specify the table containing the records you want to delete."

The second suggestion worked. Thanks a lot!